# Changing UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have iOS App which is master-detail view app. By default is masterview tableview and detailview is clasic `UIViewController`. Now, I need to change `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController`, so I've in `detailViewController.h` changed this

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
```

into this:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController
```

And in .xib file, I have set a custom Class to `DetailViewController`, so it should work... But it didn't... When I try to run app, it returns an error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "DetailViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Where is problem please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. Don't use the templates. 2. Don't use xibs.

Comment: Make sure that have set up DetailViewController as a tableview in your xib file.

Comment: Dasdom: and what should I do than? How can I do it without xib?

Answer (score 4):

You have to delete your view controller object in the xib file and use their UITableViewController from the Utilities tab. So changing subclass in code is not enough, you need to make sure you used proper template in the xib as well.